# How to build a testing class

Tags: java

I'm currently creating a program for a specific specification. I have completed the first task, and to prove it runs correctly i'm required to "write a simple class called PizzaBuild which contains a main method which demonstrates this working."

Does anyone have any tips on doing this, because i've no idea how to do it unless i literally copy all the code into the one class, but that'd defeat the purpose.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just `import` your pizza class into the class containing the main method.

Comment: 1. Create a new class in a different file with name `PizzaBuild`. 2. Add a `main` method i.e. `public static void main(String[] args)` in it. 3. Complete the `main` method to demonstrate your class (let me guess, your `Pizza` class) works accordingly.

Comment: import your class from the first task, create a second class called PizzaBuild and in the main method create an instance of the first class and call the methods you need to "build" a pizza.

Answer (score 0):

If your two classes are in the same project, you can write the new class as if it has visibility of the other.

ie)

`Pizza p = new Pizza();`

and then exercise it

`System.out.println(p.pepperoni);`  or something

Otherwise, as people have mentioned above, you can import the file and then use it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You've written a class that you say works. Since we don't know it's name, for our purposes, we'll call it `MyClass`.  `MyClass` also has some methods which, when used, demonstrates that `MyClass` works properly.

```
public class PizzaBuild
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass mine = new MyClass();

        mine.method1();

        mine.method2();

        // and so on
    }
}
```